# Can Andrica's conjecture be proven by proving a tighter upper bound for prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I checked some differences between square roots of various natural numbers and I am wondering what is required to prove Andrica's conjecture. Would a tighter upper bound for the prime gap above $n$ be sufficient? Would prime gaps have to be bounded by the product of a constant and the square root of $n$ for this conjecture to be proved?

Does Andrica's conjecture imply anything about prime gaps?

Comment: It *is* a prime gap conjecture.

Comment: Both questions are answered in the preface to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture).

Comment: So my recommendation, Jeffrey, would be to read the Wikipedia piece and then post a summary as an answer.

Comment: Ok. I had read through some webpages about Andrica's conjecture but was I was not clear about what is required to prove it. Now that I know the answers are there, I will seek them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrica's conjecture is
$$
g_n<2\sqrt{p_n}+1,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\sqrt{p_n+g_n}-\sqrt{p_n}<1,
$$
where $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$ is the n-th prime gap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Andrica's conjecture can be proven by proving a tight enough bound for the prime gap above $n$.

If prime gaps above $n$ for all $n \geq 7$ are bounded by the constant 2 multiplied by a prime < $\sqrt n$, then Andrica's conjecture is true because for Andrica's conjecture to be proven, it would have to be proven that the prime gap above $n$ is bounded by the constant 2 multiplied by $\sqrt n$.

As to what Andrica's conjecture implies will require investigation.

Comment: It certainly does not imply that prime gaps are bounded! $O(\sqrt n)$ is a long way from $O(1).$